# почему time.deltaTime работает неправильно. и выдаёт очень маленькое число

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать таймер на unity, но time.deltaTime выдаёт 0.0251761
и сбрасывается. Почему так происходит?

Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Food : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Foodcount = 100;
    public float time;
    public Text foodtext;
    public Health hl;
    public float speedsubhealth;
    public int subhealthcount;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(Time.deltaTime);
        float dubtime = 0;
        dubtime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (dubtime > time)
        {
            subfood();
            //Debug.Log(Time.time);
            time += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Foodcount <= 0)
        {
            if (dubtime > speedsubhealth)
            {
                hl.health = hl.health - subhealthcount;
                //Debug.Log(Time.time);
                speedsubhealth += Time.deltaTime;
            }        
    }


    void subfood()
    {
        if (Foodcount < 5)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Foodcount = Foodcount - 5;
            foodtext.text = Foodcount.ToString();
        }
        
        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: А в документации что сказано по поводу того, что такое `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: И чего в целом ты хочешь достичь?

Comment: А сколько должно выдавать?

Comment: Ну вон у вас комментарий даже там есть "Update is called once per frame". У вас порядка 1/0.025 = 40 фреймов в секунду, видимо, получается. Вполне нормальная цифра. Может вам нужен `FixedUpdate`, а не `Update`?